# Python Google-Style DocString for Function with No Arguments

Tags: python, documentation, docstring, google-style-guide

I've been using the Google-Style Python Docstring format for a while now. The way I've been handling functions/methods with no arguments suddenly doesn't look correct to me. I did a bit of searching and couldn't find anything online that specified how to handle that situation.

When there is no return, I've seen `None` used and I'm okay with that because that *is* technically what gets returned. However, using `None` for the args can imply that there's actually a single argument that's expected to be of the type: `NoneType`.

Currently, what I've been doing looks something like this:

```
def foo():
    """
    blah blah blah

    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        The number 5
    """
    return 5
```

My question is, which format should I use instead (I prefer to always have an `Args` section)? Or perhaps my current approach isn't really that bad and is common practice.

Some other candidates (feel free to provide your own if you feel there's a better format):

```
def foo():
    """
    blah blah blah

    Args:

    Returns:
        The number 5
    """
    return 5
```

```
def foo():
    """
    blah blah blah

    Args:
        No arguments
    Returns:
        The number 5
    """
    return 5
```

```
def foo():
    """
    blah blah blah

    Returns:
        The number 5
    """
    return 5
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me like the standard is to not have an 'Arguments' section if there are no arguments to the function. The same style as the final candidate you listed.

This is not explicitly mentioned, but I inferred this from the examples at:

- https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html
- https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html